# Установка размера родительского элемента по размеру дочернего

Tags: html, css

Как установить размер родительского элемента по размеру дочернего при условии, что у дочернего `position: absolute`?

Пример:

```css
img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src='//graph.facebook.com/1677397882490947/picture?type=large'>
</div>
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что никак. А зачем такое нужно?

Comment: Если только через javascript

Comment: Затем, что нужны вспомогательные элементы позиционированные относительно вертикально и горизонтально центрированного изображения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое - для `position: absolute` всегда указывайте размер, даже если у вас стоит 
 `display: block`, потому что изначально размер у блока `position: absolute` равен нулю.

Второе - при установке свойства `position: absolute` элемент 'выскакивает' из основного потока

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div> <!-- position: absolute -->
</div>
```

Так вот, `parent` думает, что у него нет потомков, потому что `child` теперь не в основном потоке, и не знает его размеров, а значит и не может под них подстроиться

Поэтому, как советуют в комментариях это можно сделать, только с помощью js

```js
/* уберите js и увидите разницу */

var parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
var child = document.querySelector(".child");

var cWidth = child.offsetWidth;
var cHeight = child.offsetHeight;

parent.style.width = cWidth + "px";
parent.style.height = cHeight + "px";
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <!-- position: absolute -->
</div>
```